# Reverse text word by word

Tags: vba, text, macros, ms-word

I want to reverse words in a Word document like this: "elpmaS texT" becomes "Sample Text".

I tried something like this:

```
For Each word In ActiveDocument.Words
    word = StrReverse(word)
Next word
```

However it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

When you are using a for each loop, you are unable to change the word, so use a for loop:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count Step 1

    ActiveDocument.Words(i) = StrReverse(ActiveDocument.Words(i)) & " "
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I do this for the selected text?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ReverseSelectedWords()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim oWords As Words
    Dim oWord As Range

    Set oWords = Selection.Range.Words

    For i = 1 To oWords.Count Step 1

        Set oWord = oWords(i)

        ''Make sure the word range doesn't include a space
        Do While oWord.Characters.Last.text = " "
            Call oWord.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1)
        Loop

        Debug.Print "'" & oWord.text & "'"
        oWord.text = StrReverse(oWord.text)

    Next i

End Sub
```